# eclipse: can't change C/C++ build settings (for adding gprof)

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile, flags, gprof

I want to analyze a C++ code in eclipse with GPROF.
I added the code that I want to analyze with `"new -> Makefile Project with Existing Code"` because I got it as open source from the Internet and now I want to profile it. I'm working with gprof and with eclipse for the first time.

My problem is, that when I go to `"project -> properties -> C/C++ build -> settings"` I don't see anything more than `"Binary Parsers"` and `"Error Parsers"`. I can't add flags (e.g. `-pg`) for the Compiler and Linker. It might have something to do with the Makefile Project?!
(Unfortunately I can't add my screenshot because of to less reputation).

How can I use gprof now? Can I add flags to Compiler and Linker somewhere else?

Thank you!
aciams

EDIT:

The Makefile has been created with cmake. So I added `-pg` to every file that does not begin with `"# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!"`.
When I build the project again I find `-pg` in

```
# compile CXX with /usr/bin/c++
CXX_FLAGS = -O3 -DNDEBUG  -Wall -g -pg
```

but when I run the program and search for a file named `"gmon.out"` nothing can be found. Do I have to set -pg to the Linker explicitly?

This is the important part of CMakeLists.txt:

```
project()
#set ( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug )
set ( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release )
#set ( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "icpc" )
#set ( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++-4.2" )
add_definitions ( -Wall -g -pg)
if (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux")
    if(${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} MATCHES "icpc")
        set ( OPENMP_FLAG "-openmp" )
        set ( OPENMP_LINK "-openmp" )
        else()
                set ( OPENMP_FLAG "-fopenmp" )
                set ( OPENMP_LINK "-lgomp" )
        endif(${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} MATCHES "icpc")
elseif (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Darwin")
    if(${CMAKE_GENERATOR} MATCHES "Makefile")
        find_package ( OpenMP REQUIRED )
        set ( OPENMP_FLAG "-fopenmp" )
        set ( OPENMP_LINK "-lgomp" )
        #set ( APP_TYPE MACOSX_BUNDLE )
    else()
        set ( OPENMP_FLAG "-fopenmp" )
            set ( OPENMP_LINK "" )
    endif(${CMAKE_GENERATOR} MATCHES "Makefile")
else()
    set ( OPENMP_FLAG "" )
    set ( OPENMP_LINK "" )
endif()
set ( CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")
set ( CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH 
    ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}
    /sw
    /opt
    /opt/local
    /Users/$ENV{USER}/Development
    ./include
    ./lib
    )
include ( ${QT_USE_FILE} )
include_directories (
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} )
set ( EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH build/release )

set_source_files_properties ( test.cpp test2.cpp
    PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS ${OPENMP_FLAG}
    )
add_executable ( )
target_link_libraries ()
install (  )
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would say you'd have to change the compiler flags in your Makefile script(s) ...

Comment: Okay, thanks, I tried. See the edits (:

Comment: Once you compile with `-pg` the profiling results should get created every time you run your program (after it exists successfully!) in the same directory. However having your code optimized could yield some really weird profiling data.

Comment: oh I got it (: thank you! now I added SET( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "-pg" ) to CMakeLists.txt as well and it works (:

Comment: Just check the console build output of your program. If you have '-pg's in there it's all good. Are you running your application from the command line, or are you launching it from within eclipse?